# Shower Panel Leaking Supply Line

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, leak

I have a discontinued Hansgrohe Raindance shower panel (model [27005000](https://hansgrohe-store.ru/img_gr/files/151114145123245.pdf)).  The braided cold water supply line has developed a leak (the leaky cold water line has plastic food wrap around it)

[image: View of leaky hose]
[image: Front view]

I am in the process of finding the replacement part, which I believe should be [95539000](https://hansgrohe-store.ru/img_gr/files/151114145123245.pdf) or [13099001](https://s2.img-b.com/faucet.com/mediabase/specifications/hansgrohe/141695/hruh0136.pdf).  While I am finding and verifying the part, I would like to cap the line so it doesn't waste water.  My questions:

1. What part should I get from the hardware store to cap the line and stop the leak?
2. Are the thread sizes standard?  The elbow connection from the wall is from Hansgrohe but I'm hoping that I can just buy something from the local hardware store  (I did go to Home Depot but saw that all their supply lines have hex nuts on both ends)
3. Is there any way to repair the hose? E.g., buy a braided new hose and re-use the proprietary connectors from the original to build a new hose.
4. Does anyone have experience with this panel and know how you remove the hose from the side that does *not* have the hex nut?

I'm not very familiar with plumbing repair so any help and advice is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.